# profile JavaScript in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, profiling

I am the first one in my office trying to profile java script. So there is no guidance for me.

The question may be present on StackOverflow already. But those answers are not satisfied me. That's why I made a new thread.

Can any one tell me how to profile the JavaScript in my java application in Chrome?

I found such links that how to profile JavaScript. But this is not clear for me to get a good start up. The URLs are:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/
- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Can any one suggest me a good tutorial or blog to get better startup or you can say your own way to profile JavaScript in Chrome.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I've tested few profiling tools and I find **IE profiler** (inside the build-in dev tool) be the best to start. Its easy, quite reliable. Good thing about it is that IE engine is a lot slower than Chrome so it's easier to pinpoint slow and heavy code (since you will have seconds rather than milliseconds of execution time).

If you want sth more hardcore then I would advise [**Ajax DynaTrace**](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html)
It's full-featured software (not free though). 
Chrome profiler is just weird in my opinion and while a lot of people probably use it successfully I never get any satisfactory info from it.

To enable IE Profiler:

1. Open IE browser.
2. Press F12 (developer tool shows up)
3. Go to *Profiler Tab*.
4. Hit *Start profiler* (My browser is in polish, but it will say something
   like it).
5. Do something on your page.
6. Hit *Stop profiler*.

Now you can either show results as all *Functions* or as *Execution tree*

The Tree is cool thing you want to use, because it will show you all separate (in context) execution stacks (like let's say a REST call). Now you can expand the tree and go to all the way down deep to see which functions on this stack take the most of the time.

Be aware that some functions (native) like .apply cannot be expanded to see whats inside (profiler will tell you that).

Functions view will just show all the functions that profiler found, their execution time and count (so you can which one is called the most time and what overall time it took).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you suggest any useful links for IE profiler ?

Comment: Updated the post. Links? Sry no, ive learned all this by experimenting :)

Comment: Thanks for reply...I have some queries foe basic startup function. Can u please come for chat ?